# roslaunch launching not in one package

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

after long time I followed the tutorials again and tried a lauch file

```
    <group ns="turtlesim1">
            <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
    </group>

    <node pkg="turtlesim" name="mimic" type="mimic">
            <remap from="input" to="turtlesim1/turtle1"/>
            <remap from="output" to="turtlesim2/turtle1"/>
    </node>
    <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="turtle_teleop_key"  output="screen">
            <param name="scale_linear" value="0.5" type="double"/>
            <param name="scale_angular" value="1.5" type="double"/>
            <remap from="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop"/>
    </node>
```

however the teleop is not working with the turtlesim

how would I correctly use teleop_key in a launchfile so that it work with the turtlesim ?

Thanks for any hint/link to the correct tutorial
Regards,
RL

---

Edit: Remapping is only for names  ? only makes sense with long names ?
is there any way to reuse the turtle_teleop_key in another package/ with another topic ?

this worked for me

```
<launch>
<group ns="turtlesim1">
        <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
    <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="turtle_teleop_key" output="screen">
            <param name="scale_linear" value="0.5" type="double"/>
            <param name="scale_angular" value="1.5" type="double"/>
    </node> 
</group>
</launch>
```

thanks and regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262404/roslaunch-launching-not-in-one-package/) by [RL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30497/rl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-24**:
@RL: please don't post answers unless you are actually answering your own question. For everything else, just post comments *or* update your original question. Use the *edit* button/link for that.

**Comment by [RL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30497/rl/) on 2017-05-24**:
just noticed that..sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the [turtlesim](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim) package tells you that it is subscribing to `turtleX/cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/Twist)`.  That means that it gets Messages of Type geometry_msgs/Twist at the Topic named `turtleX/cmd_vel`. The X is a placeholder for the current number of the turtle.

On the other hand we have the teleop node which is publishing to a Topic named `turtle1/cmd_vel` of type geometry_msgs/Twist by default. So what I don't know where you got `<remap from="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop"/>` from. But normally with remap you can change a topic name. For example you can change the topicname from `turtle1/cmd_vel` to `turtle2/cmd_vel` with `<remap from="turtle1/cmd_vel" to="turtle2/cmd_vel"/>`.

So just to explain how it is working.

Another thing what you currently doing is `<group ns="turtlesim1">`
So this puts all the topics of the nodes you have in this group like f.e. the topic `turtleX/cmd_vel` in a group namespace. So in your case the topic name changes to `turtlesim1/turtleX/cmd_vel`.

And thats your current problem. By default the teleop is publishing to `turtle1/cmd_vel`. Your turtlesim subscribes after doing the namespace to `turtlesim1/turtle1/cmd_vel`. And this actually doesn't match!

I do not know if I should give you now the concrete solution. Perhaps you can try it on your own after this explaining and if you have further problems we can talk about it.

Didnt mentioned or checked the correctness of mimic by now. We talk abut this later too.

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0